# Multiplying a 2d array by a 1d array in PHP using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

let me start off by saying what I have works just fine. However, I was wondering if there was a method using foreach loops, instead of while loops, that will return the same result. My current code is:

```
$a[0] = $_GET['a1'];
$a[1] = $_GET['a2'];
$a[2] = $_GET['a3'];
$a[3] = $_GET['a4'];
$a[4] = $_GET['a5'];
$a[5] = $_GET['a6'];
$a[6] = $_GET['a7'];
$a[7] = $_GET['a8'];
$a[8] = $_GET['a9'];
$a[9] = $_GET['a10'];
$a[10] = $_GET['a11'];
$a[11] = $_GET['a12'];
$a[12] = $_GET['a13'];
$a[13] = $_GET['a14'];
$a[14] = $_GET['a15'];
$a[15] = $_GET['a16'];
$a[16] = $_GET['a17'];
$a[17] = $_GET['a18'];
$a[18] = $_GET['a19'];
$a[19] = $_GET['a20'];
$a[20] = $_GET['a21'];
$a[21] = $_GET['a22'];
$a[22] = $_GET['a23'];
$a[23] = $_GET['a24'];
$a[24] = $_GET['a25'];
$a[25] = $_GET['a26'];
$a[26] = $_GET['a27'];
$a[27] = $_GET['a28'];
$array1 = array(
    array(-0.0165333833412173,-0.805148897111146,-0.253228140499216,-0.184436610496828,-0.182460815146422,-0.562680616467753),
    array(0.0530980021095432,0.197367160352892,0.486754591654999,0.100148472516492,0.129649075750223,-0.0891313538023273),
    array(1.20820560236013,1.60297691019929,1.88645801788488,1.4097784563,1.35491780171462,1.83839262576814),
    array(0.35474704442591,0.669288291278341,-0.618871707987998,0.314393917137463,0.369309934864932,0.302877707428276),
    array(1.73737846681824,1.23045039205127,1.74985170545799,2.53444768504332,0.947425891979588,2.49693773110446),
    array(1.08515864048978,1.19974869194067,1.40391203998614,0.645993089768699,1.18500365352365,0.183710871687018),
    array(-0.158201130751605,0.245894811416122,-0.13491139550657,0.268781009345758,0.584094496717681,-0.475038989317082),
    array(2.69120997158388,2.6335032877555,2.1678974119528,1.98159587601917,2.47871441914596,3.11218576826585),
    array(1.58301428618536,1.4690581543491,1.64181831092486,1.31270093574087,0.956030437566211,1.68095459548238),
    array(0.567053945109392,0.672686283651576,0.50520628014895,0.573859412747649,0.906581004455213,0.675935843127413),
    array(2.21154924140175,2.4629227185282,2.44302564998387,1.76594656224375,2.24292394905905,2.46555856986067),
    array(0.789058773638184,0.56494483459565,1.02220848055446,0.740827710977414,0.0568788365193514,0.974084436394248),
    array(-1.22527151151768,-0.37116067796664,-0.993915606653743,-0.265414040283105,-0.0483919594705323,-1.26478189171631),
    array(1.93198111668015,0.978691339072353,0.896606685235391,1.43344220993764,1.44428119515243,0.832846974841109),
    array(0.0960968892129648,0.179429676667834,0.653561055735465,0.611111687937286,0.420917607921928,0.788124847059183),
    array(-0.570188484564322,-0.367869613869776,-0.425708923999659,0.58428081962228,0.431696028180505,-0.560777966949268),
    array(2.18753554884398,2.10453220450978,2.18396016604212,1.53663043726462,1.6128493800773,2.47023229651768),
    array(0.933680338305853,0.701683572817621,1.05817969240128,1.13326689801564,1.06305023491714,1.28172788495342),
    array(0.237030103809889,1.19429662809383,1.32352397170755,0.787441428409051,1.06861486730769,0.196323518345157),
    array(1.27102015175144,0.999617071482296,1.14337292692749,1.79352497701309,1.14261585172827,1.18874166503307),
    array(0.746730730970985,0.584005303699165,0.00845233248507581,0.617844244971367,0.646839413026708,0.393004935019083),
    array(1.33877796293032,1.18403793988876,1.16686497194317,1.18487924665819,0.796233877768925,1.21668080067963),
    array(1.66146357909026,1.52622605987311,1.51673796371559,2.45659237209795,1.58826974938031,1.87667392945756),
    array(1.23205756178945,1.25461474916892,1.0738857243227,1.21949513612512,0.847503017550969,1.33075294766838),
    array(0.976236852070675,1.0676137689421,1.08390543200419,1.19114160706157,0.804407032221587,0.918305581716723),
    array(1.0514345299356,1.24825633668808,1.15750685444102,1.34538988886631,1.24490007119083,0.994386901437322),
    array(-50.5445732202499,-53.6034355984409,-52.2301074110166,-59.4416059910645,-50.3559798265968,-51.5135149950383),
);
$array2 = array();
$x = 0;
while($x < COUNT($array1)){
    $y = 0;
    while($y < COUNT($array1[$x])){
        $array2[$x][$y] = $array1[$x][$y] * $a[$x];
        //echo($array2[$x][$y] . ', ');
        $y++;
    }
    //echo('<br>');
    $x++;   
}
```

Again, while this works, I am trying to get into the habit of writing cleaner code. Additionally, I am still relatively new to PHP, so I'm still struggling a bit with  some of its syntax and structuring.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work identical to what you have.

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($a as $k1=>$a1)
{
   foreach($array1[$k1] as $k2=>$a2)
   {
      $array2[$k1][$k2] = $a2 * $a1;
   }
}
```

The basic format of a foreach loop is `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` if you don't need the array key, you can shorten it to `foreach($array as $value)`.

Comment: Thank's a bunch, this is perfect, and the explanation was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the code by directly accessing the `$_GET` values instead of copying them into `$a`.

```
$result = array();

foreach($array1 as $k1 => $array2) {
    foreach($array2 as $k2 => $value) {
        $result[$k1][$k2] = $value * $_GET['a'.($k1+1)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea, thanks for the tip! Can't believe I've never thought of using concatenation in a loop like that for my $_GET 's